# How to get value of a particular field from a string in Qt

Tags: c++, qt, substring, qstring

How can i get value of a particular query field in Qt.
Consider the following string

```
"plugin://plugin.video.youtube/?action=play_video&videoid=4fVCKy69zUY"
```

I want the value of videoid i.e 4fVCKy69zUY in form of a string how can i do this.

Comment: Can you be clear how this relates to QT? If you simply have a variable of type `string`, a simple regular expression would handle it for sure, but as you clearly mention QT, it is not clear that this is the case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can retrieve the text after `videoid=` using `QString::mid` :

```
QString str = "plugin://plugin.video.youtube/?action=play_video&videoid=4fVCKy69zUY";
QString strToFind = "videoid=";
QString value = str.mid(str.indexOf(strToFind)+strToFind.length());
```

Answer (score 1):

Since it is a URL you're trying to deconstruct, it would make sense to use the dedicated `QUrl` and `QUrlQuery` classes:

```
QUrl url("plugin://plugin.video.youtube/?action=play_video&videoid=4fVCKy69zUY");
QUrlQuery q(url);

QString videoid = q.queryItemValue("videoid");
```

`QUrlQuery` has a constructor accepting a `QString`, so

```
QUrlQuery q("plugin://plugin.video.youtube/?action=play_video&videoid=4fVCKy69zUY");
```

also works if you really just want to extract the video id from the URL, but I suspect that `QUrl` may be useful to you in other ways.

Alternatively, using a regular expression:

```
QString url = "plugin://plugin.video.youtube/?action=play_video&videoid=4fVCKy69zUY";

// Regex to match the videoid. The capture ID is only the ID itself (between
// the parentheses): everything after "videoid=" that is not an ampersand,
// which is where the videoid ends and the next parameter begins.
QRegExp re("videoid=([^&]*)");

// apply it
re.indexIn(url);

// extract the capture
QString videoid = re.cap(1);
```

Answer (score 0):

I think `Qstring.mid(int index , int len)` can help you